# Custom notification tone is not playing on emulator

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications

I am setting a custom tone for notifications. The notification is received via Firebase messaging data payload. The message is displayed correctly but the custom tone is not played. What is the problem? Here is the code

```
override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {

     val sound =  Uri.parse("android.resource://" + applicationContext.packageName +"/"+R.raw.tone)


    if (remoteMessage.data.isNotEmpty()) {
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT)
        val channelId = "Default"
        val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources,R.drawable.ic_logo))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_logo)
            .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.data["title"]).setVisibility(VISIBILITY_PRIVATE)
            .setSound(sound)
            .setContentText(remoteMessage.data["body"]).setAutoCancel(true).setContentIntent(pendingIntent).setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MAX)
        val manager = getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        {
            val attributes = AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                .build()
            val channel = NotificationChannel(channelId, "Default channel", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
            channel.setSound(sound, attributes)
        }
        manager.notify(0, builder.build())
    }
}
```